# Convert an existing asp.net mvc to act as Security Token Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wif

I have an existing asp.net mvc application (Pivotal) with its own authentication mechanism.  I want to use this as a Security Token Service for Windows Identity Foundation so that other related web applications can use Pivotal for authentication.

The WIF docs claim that a web app can be used as a STS, but provide no examples.  I can't find anything online that relates to the current versions .net/WIF.  I am using VS 2017, .net 4.52, c# and MVC 5.  The examples that I have found related to VS2012 and don't work in VS2017.

Are there any guides or examples that can help?

Comment: I really wouldn't. Use an established system which has already fixed all the subtle bugs that'll probably get introduced when trying to create your own security system, especially one which is essentially a b**tardised web app

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree with "don't roll your own" but if you want to, [refer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804740.aspx) this.

Then [convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/security/guidelines-for-migrating-an-application-built-using-wif-3-5-to-wif-4-5) 3.5 to 4.5.